# GraphQL query not fetching successfully in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have attempted to use GraphQL in React by using the

`useQuery` api like such:

```
    const {loading, data, error} = useQuery<BaseUser, BaseUserVars>(
        GET_DASHBOARD_USER, 
        {variables: {id: "1"}}
    )
```

In my API folder, I have the needed interfaces and queries saved like such:

```
export interface BaseUser {
    id: string 
    username: string
    age: number
    goal: Goal
    tasks: [{
      id: string, 
      description: string,
      completedAt: string | null,
      expirationDate: string
    }]

}

export interface BaseUserVars {
    id: string
}

export const GET_DASHBOARD_USER = gql`
    query userWithTasks($id: String!){
    user(id: $id){
    id 
    username
    biography
    goal
    tasks {
     id
     description
     completedAt
     expirationDate
    }
    }
  }`
```

I get a `400 bad response` error when I run the query. I try to call a function, that i have defined in my backend resolver called `userWithTask`

In the playground, i have used it without the `query` keyword, where it worked fine:

```
{
  userWithTasks(id: "1"){
    id 
    username
    biography
    goal
    tasks {
     id
     description
     completedAt
     expirationDate
    }
  }
}
```

The syntax should be correct, what is the issue?

UPDATE:

this is the error message i get `Cannot query field "user" on type "Query". Did you mean "users"?`

Here is my backend resolver for refrence:

```
 @Query(() => User)
  async userWithTasks(@Args("id") id: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userService.getUserByIdWithTasks(id);
    console.log(user)
    return user
  }
```

Comment: Surely that "*`400 bad response` error*" has a more specific error message?

Comment: Your `GET_DASHBOARD_USER` is querying the `user` field, not the `userWithTasks` field.

Comment: `Response not successful: Received status code 400`

Comment: If you go to the header response on the devtool I think you can see the apollo message error. With that you can debug easily a bad request in graphql. Could you send me the error message ?

Comment: Yes thanks @HamzaKhattabi i will update with the error message

Comment: I have also added the backend resolver for reference

Comment: Thanks for the update. "*Cannot query field "user" on type "Query".*" is pretty clear. As I said before, you want to use `userWithTask` instead of `user` in your query.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake so the `query [name]` is actually just an arbitrary name for the query?

Comment: Yes, the operation name is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user doesn't exist in your query field. In the playground you call userWithTasks and not user. When you are making a request when gql you have to "duplicate" the fields first with the typed parameters and second the parameters values.

```
  export const GET_DASHBOARD_USER = gql`
        query userWithTasks($id: String!){
        userWithTasks(id: $id){
        id 
        username
        biography
        goal
        tasks {
         id
         description
         completedAt
         expirationDate
        }
        }
      }`
```